# how to set hint text in Zefyr in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [Zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr) Text Editor, actually, it's a nice rich text package. But I don't know how to set hint Zefyr TextEditor?

But it helps to load our content but deleting hint content not a good idea.

```
class createNote extends State {
  ZefyrController _controller;
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    final document = _loadDocument();
    _controller = ZefyrController(document);

    _focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  NotusDocument _loadDocument() {
    final Delta delta = Delta()..insert("\n"); //import quill_delta
    return NotusDocument.fromDelta(delta);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create Note"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: ZefyrScaffold(
          child: ZefyrEditor(
            //mode: ZefyrMode.select,
            controller: _controller,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```